# Visual Studio 2019 Setup Wizard - Adding desktop shortcut with file path

Tags: visual-studio, shortcut, setup-wizard

I try to create a shortcut with setup wizard but it doesn't give the path of the original programm. When i start my application from application folder all works fine (i make the changes in my register with my programm). But if i start the application from the desktop shortcut  it seems like before application runs is starting a installation setup located in (C:\Windows\Installer\401863.msi) and reset all my changes of register.
How to make an desktop shortcu (during the installation) from Primary output or in another way to have desktop shortcut with the path to original .exe application ?

Comment: How did you create the shortcut? Please check if you have created a shortcut for "Primary output".

Comment: I added the Primary output from the main project. And from it i creted shorcut to desktop. That shorcut don't idicate where is the main file path, it show me that is on desktop. It indicate only WorkingFolder of application.